# How to add the current session file name in the status line in Vim?

Tags: session, vim

I recently added the [sessionman](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2010) plugin to my Vim configuration, and I like it so far.

I understand that Vim sets `v:this_session` to the session file name when a session is being used and I’d like to add it to my status line. Unfortunately, `v:this_session` contains the full file path and it is often way too long for it to fit in the status line.

So my question is: How can I extract the file name without its full path from `v:this_session` and add it to my status line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, Vim has the `:help filename-modifiers` like `:t` for the last component of the file. You can use them with the `fnamemodify()` function (or `expand()` if you want to modify a built-in Vim file identifier like `%`):

```
:echo fnamemodify(v:this_session, ':t')
```

Comment: It's a useful routine!  I was not aware of it for some reason (even though it was introduced in version 5.2!).  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Just a note that might help people: when testing this I had the statusline not showing anything as soon as I loaded a session and couldn't figure out why. Turns out the session actually stores the statusline value so any session saved **before** the statusline was updated, was incorrectly changing it back on load. The solution was simply to delete any `statusline` entry in the session file.

Answer (score 1):

Since the forward slash character is used as path separator in Vim on all
operating systems, to obtain the filename from a full path it is sufficient to
extract the last component of the path.  For doing that one can can use the
`matchstr()` or `substitute()` functions:

```
substitute(t, '^.*/', '', '')
```

or

```
matchstr(t, '[^/]*$')
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on how to write the status line to include this in it ?

Comment: @ereOn:  Just use a `%{}`-field when configuring the `statusline` option as usual.  For example, `:set statusline+=%{matchstr(t,'[^/]*$')}` or `:let &statusline += '%{matchstr(t, "[^/]*$")}'`.  For additional information on Vim status line configuration search on StackOverflow (or on the Internet, in general).  It is a well [covered](http://got-ravings.blogspot.com/2008/08/vim-pr0n-making-statuslines-that-own.html) topic.